# Индикатор времени сообщения, дизайн

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, интерфейс

Пытаюсь спроектировать chat-bubble для мессенджера. Никак не могу разобраться, как отображать индикатор времени сообщения, как в Telegram:

[image: индикатор времени сообщения]

Нужно, чтобы текст был закреплен к углу bubble-а, и не перекрывался текстом.

Comment: все дело в разметке вашего bubble, приложите ее в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос частично решил, решение нашел [здесь](https://gist.github.com/trivalent/00526294fa38072a6034f5dc5910824a):

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ChatBubbleLayout extends FrameLayout {

    public ChatBubbleLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ChatBubbleLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ChatBubbleLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(21)
    public ChatBubbleLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        TextView message_textView = (TextView) getChildAt(0);
        View localView = getChildAt(1);

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int view_size = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        Layout messageTextviewLayout = message_textView.getLayout();

        int linestart = messageTextviewLayout.getLineStart(messageTextviewLayout.getLineCount() - 1);
        int lineend = messageTextviewLayout.getLineEnd(messageTextviewLayout.getLineCount() - 1);

        int desiredWidth = (int) Layout.getDesiredWidth(message_textView.getText()
                .subSequence(linestart, lineend), message_textView.getPaint());

        int measuredWidth = message_textView.getMeasuredWidth();

        int requiredWidth = Math.min(measuredWidth,
                (int) Math.ceil(Layout.getDesiredWidth(message_textView.getText(),
                        message_textView.getPaint())) + message_textView.getPaddingRight() +
                        message_textView.getPaddingLeft());

        if (view_size - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight()
                >= requiredWidth + localView.getMeasuredWidth()) {
            setMeasuredDimension(requiredWidth + localView.getMeasuredWidth() +
                    getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight(), getMeasuredHeight());
        } else if ((requiredWidth - message_textView.getPaddingLeft() - message_textView.getPaddingRight()
                < desiredWidth + localView.getMeasuredWidth())) {
            setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(),
                    getMeasuredHeight() + localView.getMeasuredHeight());
        }
    }
}
```